# Replace multiple characters from multiple columns in R

Tags: r, dplyr

Given a dataframe as follows:

```
structure(list(date = structure(1:24, .Label = c("2010Y1-01m", 
"2010Y1-02m", "2010Y1-03m", "2010Y1-04m", "2010Y1-05m", "2010Y1-06m", 
"2010Y1-07m", "2010Y1-08m", "2010Y1-09m", "2010Y1-10m", "2010Y1-11m", 
"2010Y1-12m", "2011Y1-01m", "2011Y1-02m", "2011Y1-03m", "2011Y1-04m", 
"2011Y1-05m", "2011Y1-06m", "2011Y1-07m", "2011Y1-08m", "2011Y1-09m", 
"2011Y1-10m", "2011Y1-11m", "2011Y1-12m"), class = "factor"), 
    a = structure(c(1L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 22L, 23L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 
    7L, 8L, 10L, 1L, 21L, 3L, 6L, 9L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
    16L, 17L), .Label = c("--", "10159.28", "10295.69", "10580.82", 
    "10995.65", "11245.84", "11327.23", "11621.99", "12046.63", 
    "12139.78", "12848.27", "13398.26", "13962.6", "14559.72", 
    "14982.58", "15518.64", "15949.87", "7363.45", "8237.71", 
    "8830.99", "9309.47", "9316.56", "9795.77"), class = "factor"), 
    b = structure(c(2L, 16L, 23L, 24L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 10L, 12L, 
    14L, 17L, 1L, 22L, 3L, 5L, 8L, 11L, 13L, 15L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
    21L), .Label = c("-", "--", "1058.18", "1455.6", "1539.01", 
    "1867.07", "2036.92", "2102.23", "2372.84", "2693.96", "2769.65", 
    "2973.04", "3146.88", "3227.23", "3604.71", "365.07", "3678.01", 
    "4043.18", "4438.55", "4860.76", "5360.94", "555.51", "653.19", 
    "980.72"), class = "factor"), c = structure(c(2L, 6L, 10L, 
    11L, 13L, 15L, 16L, 18L, 20L, 22L, 24L, 7L, 1L, 9L, 12L, 
    14L, 17L, 19L, 21L, 23L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 8L), .Label = c("-", 
    "--", "1092.73", "1222.48", "1409.07", "158.18", "1748.44", 
    "2179.42", "227.68", "268.53", "331.81", "366.95", "434.19", 
    "486.41", "538.49", "606.62", "614.75", "651.46", "729.44", 
    "736.55", "836.46", "890.81", "929.72", "981.65"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-24L))
```

How could I replace `--` and `-` in only columns `a` and `b` with `NA`? Thanks.

Comment: How are you reading the data in? Maybe you should look at avoiding the problem when it's being read in (using `na.strings`, for example). That way, the column types would also be correct.

Comment: I'm using `read.xlsx` read it.

Comment: Have you tried using the `na.strings` argument in `read.xlsx`?

Comment: You mean by adding `na.strings = c('--', '-')`?

Comment: Yes. But note that doing it while reading the data in would apply the rule to the entire dataset. If it's for specific columns, like you've indicated here, you can try the `type.convert` example I shared in my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use :

```
cols <- c('a', 'b')
df[cols][df[cols] == '--' | df[cols] == '-'] <- NA
```

Or using `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(across(c(a, b), ~replace(., . %in% c('--', '-'), NA)))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better to try to avoid the data being read in like this in the first place, but if you need to correct it after, you can try using the `na.strings` argument in `type.convert`. Notice that it's `na.strings` with an "s" -- it's plural, so more than one value can be used to represent `NA` values.

```
df[c("a", "b")] <- lapply(df[c("a", "b")], type.convert, na.strings = c("--", "-"))
str(df)
# 'data.frame':   24 obs. of  4 variables:
#  $ date: Factor w/ 24 levels "2010Y1-01m","2010Y1-02m",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
#  $ a   : num  NA 7363 8238 8831 9317 ...
#  $ b   : num  NA 365 653 981 1456 ...
#  $ c   : Factor w/ 24 levels "-","--","1092.73",..: 2 6 10 11 13 15 16 18 20 22 ...
head(df)
#         date       a       b      c
# 1 2010Y1-01m      NA      NA     --
# 2 2010Y1-02m 7363.45  365.07 158.18
# 3 2010Y1-03m 8237.71  653.19 268.53
# 4 2010Y1-04m 8830.99  980.72 331.81
# 5 2010Y1-05m 9316.56 1455.60 434.19
# 6 2010Y1-06m 9795.77 1867.07 538.49
```

---

Note that in this particular case, you could also use the side effect of `as.numeric(as.character(...))` converting anything that can't be coerced to numeric to `NA`, but keep in mind that you will get a `warning` for each column that you use this approach on.

```
lapply(df[c("a", "b")], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer.